# Angular modal popup appears at the bottom

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a modal popup with Angular 5+ and Bootstrap. The problem is that instead of appearing as a popup, it appears at the bottom, as if it was the continuation of the page. It adds itself a white background to it as well.

[image]

Now, if add this CSS code:

```
ngb-modal-window[role="dialog"] {
  display:flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 400px;
  top: 200px;   
}
```

It gets fixed and ends up looking as it was meant. The problem is that this affects all of the `ngb-modal-window[role="dialog"]` elements of the page, and I only need it for this single one. Have you encountered something like this before?

[image]

Here's how Im creating the popup:

HTML of the modal component:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h1 class="modal-title">Messages Popup</h1>
  <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('closed')"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <h5>test</h5>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary float-left" type="button" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('closed')">Done</button>
</div>
```

messagesComponent.ts:

```
export class JhiMessagesComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {

  }

  showMessagesModal(){
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(JhiMessagesModalComponent);
  }
}
```

messages-modal.component.ts:

```
export class JhiMessagesModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {

  }
```

Comment: Can you show your modal container HTML as well - that's what normally determines the position of the overlay

Comment: Is this what you mean by modal container HTML ? https://i.imgur.com/hDqYfSq.jpg The code that gets added by angular after it reads the html code of my modal component

Comment: I meant your actual HTML, not how it appears in the browser. You're probably doing something to it that is affecting its layout

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track!

I'd just add the CSS and HTML as this (Or even a selector after the modal class)

```
<div class="modal-body pop-out">
  <h5>test</h5>
</div>
```

And then use the CSS:

```
.pop-out {
  display:flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 400px;
  top: 200px;   
}
```

I'll add, this is the correct route because you have the same modal framework with different requirements, specifying optional CSS by including a class when you need a different look makes it clear where the difference comes from; And doesn't change the default behavior.

Comment: Hi! I tried something like this before but, sadly, it doesnt move the whole popup, but rather some text in it. The only way for it to properly work is to add that styling to the class I mentioned, which is "spit out" by Angular and I cannot change. I think im gonna leave angular & bootstrap and use CSS & HTML only.

Comment: @elmanqo something else weird then is probably happening. Can you create a StackBlitz that reproduces it?